# Access add to existing passthrough query via VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm curious if it's possible to add to an existing passthrough query without changing what is currently built in it.

Example; if I have a passthrough query that has the following code:

```
SELECT MailYear, offer, CompanyCode, SeasonFlag, Season_Id, Description_Full, EarlyBirdDate, Description, Price_Type, Offer_Type, Page_Count, FirstReleaseMailed, InternetActiveDate
from CatCov
where offer = 'VG'and MailYear in ('2021', '2020')
```

and I want to add something on the next line. Is this something that is possible? If so does anyone have any VBA examples they should show me or point me in the direction of?

I was trying

```
db.QueryDefs.Delete "qryMaster"

If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
rs.MoveFirst

strSELECT = "select MailYear, offer, CompanyCode, SeasonFlag, Season_Id, Description_Full, EarlyBirdDate, Description, Price_Type, Offer_Type, Page_Count, FirstReleaseMailed, InternetActiveDate " _
    & "from CatCov where offer = 'VG'and MailYear in ('2021', '2020') "

strSQL1 = strSELECT

    Set qdfPassThrough = db.CreateQueryDef("qryMaster")
    qdfPassThrough.Connect = "ODBC;DSN=SupplyChainMisc;Description=SupplyChainMisc;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=SupplyChain_Misc;"
    qdfPassThrough.ReturnsRecords = True
    qdfPassThrough.SQL = strSQL

rs.MoveNext
Do Until rs.EOF = True

strUNION = " Union SELECT MailYear, offer, CompanyCode, SeasonFlag, Season_Id, Description_Full, EarlyBirdDate, Description, Price_Type, Offer_Type, Page_Count, FirstReleaseMailed, InternetActiveDate " _
    & "from CatCov where offer = 'TK' "

strSQL2 = StrUnion

qdfPassThrough.SQL = strSQL

rs.MoveNext
Loop

Else
    MsgBox "No records"
End If
```

but that isn't working.
Since I have a loop running it errors on `If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then` saying that "Object variable or With Block variable not set". This comes up cause I added the With Statement otherwise it's fine.

I'm trying to setup a loop that will continually add to a passthrough query while not affecting what's already in there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show your complete loop code. You can modify the `.SQL` of a querydef as often as you want, but it isn't clear from your question what goes wrong.

Comment: added full loop code.

Comment: You have the right idea. After your code fails? Open up the query in design mode - it will have the results of your vba code. Now, cut and paste that right into the server side (say sql server studio - start a new blank query and cut + paste in what you have in the Access query - likely the issue is a syntax error and you need to tweak the sql you shoved into that query. After you run the VBA code, what you shoved into the PT query can be viewed in design mode - and you can even at noted cut + paste that right into SQL server studio - if it don't run, then it will not run in Access ether.

Comment: Your code seems to be simplified beyond recognition. The loop doesn't refer to fields from `rs` at all, and the `strSQL` variables are mixed up. -- And if it fails on `If Not (rs.EOF`, you need to show how `rs` is opened.